# Click on specific area of the Screen using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pyautogui

Is it possible to make Python click on a specific area of the screen? For example, I want it to move the cursor and click near the upper right corner of the screen on a specific place by itself, maybe with PyAutoGUI.

Answer (score 2):

using pyautogui this can be easily done.

you can get pyautogui using `pip install pyautogui` in the terminal.
if that didn't work use `pip install PyAutoGUI`.
than using the code bellow you can click anywhere on the screen

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.click(100,200)
                #x , y
```

read more about pyautogui [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> Try searching things in googles more often before asking question in stack overflow or other places, this could result in learning python and other thing way faster, for example when I searched your questions title the first thing that came up instantly gave me the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(100, 100)
```

Where x and y coordinates go in `.click(x, y)`

You can read the docs [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it easier for use in code.

```
import pyautogui

def click(a, b):
    pyautogui.click(a, b)

click(100, 200)
```

Comment: You could do `from pyautogui import click` and avoid the custom function.